# Query by example in Hibernate 5.2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I did query by example in hibernate 4.X version, but when I tried to do so in 5.2, it's `session.createCriteria()` is deprecated.

```
        Session session = getSession();
        Admin admin = new Admin();
        admin.setEmail(email);
        admin.setPasswd(password);
        Example adminExample = Example.create(admin);
        Criteria cq = session.createCriteria(Admin.class).add(adminExample);
```

Here's how I do in 5.2 as JPA specifications (one of the reason to deprecate the method in new release) for `criteriaQuery`. see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#appendix-legacy-criteria) for more details

```
        Session session = getSession();

        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Admin> criteria = builder.createQuery(Admin.class);
        Root<Admin> adminRoot = criteria.from(Admin.class);
        criteria.select(adminRoot);
        Predicate adminPre = builder.and(builder.equal(adminRoot.get("email"), email),
                builder.equal(adminRoot.get("password"), password));
        criteria.where(adminPre);
        List<Admin> adminList = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

So my question is, how can I use query by example in 5.2 ?

Comment: Use the new criteria, not the legacy http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria

Comment: @jklee I've already shown in my code for new `Criteria` and is working pretty fine, but I'm not getting how to use Query by example in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA Criteria does not support query by example so you need to rewrite those queries to explicit predicates.

Comment: Hey Vlad, one more thing, if `session.createCriteria()` is deprecated, why have you used it everywhere in your new documentation, I mean more than 40 times ??

Comment: What do you mean? Show me some links.

Comment: Hmm.. see this link, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria here, on first para, it says `Criteria API should be considered as deprecated`, and On chapter 29 it says **This appendix covers the legacy Hibernate org.hibernate.Criteria API, which should be considered deprecated.** , and still elaborates the deprecated way to handle things.

Comment: Criteria API means the JPA one, which is not deprecated. The legacy Hibernate-specific Criteria is deprecated. Read it carefully.

Comment: Hi Vlad, I'm stuck to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45539556/how-to-add-subqueries-like-notin-in-hibernate-5-2 and I've no idea to deal with it, and your docs too didn't mention a way to handle these sub-queries. Please guide me.

Comment: Just read the JPA spec and you will know. It's standard JPA after all.